# android get photo from camera or gallery using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-photos

I am using `FragmentPagerAdapter` with three tabs. Each tab is having multiple `fragments`, in one of these Fragment i request to get photo from Gallery or Camera. The issue is `onActivityResult()` of the parent `Activity` hosting the tab is invoked not that of the `Fragment`. Help Appreciated.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String realPath = getImageRealPath(selectedImage);
                realPaths.add(realPath);
                Glide.with(mActivity)
                        .load(realPath)
                        .into(profile_imv);
            }
            break;
        case MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE_BY_CAMERA:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String realPath = getImageRealPath(selectedImage);
                realPaths.add(realPath);
                Glide.with(mActivity)
                        .load(realPath)
                        .into(profile_imv);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is how i call the Intent both for Gallery and Camera

```
public void choosePhotoFromGallary() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY);
}

private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(mActivity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE_BY_CAMERA);
    }
}
```

This is the `MainACtivity` `onActivityResult()` code

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("USER_DETAILS");
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your gallery intent code

Answer (score 0):

Change `getActivity().startActivityForResult(..)` to `startActivityForResult(..)` this will pass the result intent to the fragment's `onActivityResult(..)`

Beautifully explained in this SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Comment: I already did it like the suggested way. no luck yet

Answer (score 0):

Override onActiviyResult() inside the fragment and re-write the code there.

Comment: I am doing same nothing happened no change.

Comment: send the complete code of activity and fragment.